# CSS/HTML/Flex Align items vertically into two columns

Tags: css, flexbox

Is there a CSS/HTML/Flexbox way to align items of varying height vertically into two columns like this?

[image]

In such a way that you remove item #3 and it realigns like this:

[image]

BONUS: They collapse into one column if the browser is too narrow.

Comment: This is called manasory grid

Comment: ... and no, right now masonry layouts cannot be achieved in pure CSS.

Comment: @Alohci, it can. see my answer bellow

Comment: @Normal - Column layout orders the boxes differently to the masonry layout requested by the OP.

Comment: To clarify, the items would come in order 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and the layout should detect which column is currently the shortest (has the highest empty space) and place the next item there.